# Screen Filter: How does UI keeps running over other applications?

Tags: android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, service

**Please Don't reply that "you can use service to keep it running in background."**

The main UI in screen filter (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor) seems to be a full screen activity, being run like a service all the time. But my understanding is, service is used to run in the background, because activity cannot keep running, when other applications are active. 
Can anybody please write whether:
- the screen (activity) is being run as part of a service ? 
- Is there any permission, that allows one app's activity to keep running over other applications activities ??

**Please read the question fully, if you are thinking to tag it as duplicate to other question.**

Comment: Well, It would be better for "whoever -1 this question" to give the reason, why this question is bad ?? or write answer if he/she knows.

Answer (score 0):

are you saying some task to run in background continuously while the in ui you are doing other task?
if so you can use the broadcast receiver, alarm manager and pending intent.
for eg

```
mbroadcastreceiver= new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {


                String link = "link needed for json to check something"

                new AsyncTaskYouWantToDo( MovieCategoriesActivity.this, mbroadcastreceiver).execute(link);
            }
        };

        registerReceiver( mbroadcastreceiver, new IntentFilter("Service you want") );

        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("your desired action"), 0 );

        am = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), "desired interval to run frequently in background", pi);
```

Answer (score 0):

The activity starts a service that overlays a view. That way the application activity is closed but the service lives on. I hope that's the answer to the question you were looking for.